# Issue on Drawing Points(Circles) Along a Specific Line

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can you please take a look at this example and let me know how I can get a Point value from the existing array , in this example the `data[]` and display the value as point on the top of eacha line?

So I have 5 element is the array as:

```
var data = [200, 20820, 32, 9999955, 7580];
```

and 5 lines as `Line1 , Line2, Line3, Line4, and Line5` so the value for Line1 = 200 and value for Line5 will be 7850.
I know there are some libraries like highcharts.js outside doing this thing but since I have very different units from decimal to big numbers for each line so I have to regenerate a new one.

```
$(function () {
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var data = [200, 20820, 32, 9999955, 7580];

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(200, 50);
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(342, 154);
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(288, 321);
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(112, 321);
ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(59, 154);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font = "12px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Line 1", 185, 30);
ctx.fillText("Line 2", 360, 155);
ctx.fillText("Line 3", 300, 355);
ctx.fillText("Line 4", 90, 355);
ctx.fillText("Line 5", 10, 155);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What's a value "as point"? And how does "point on the top of each line" translate?

Comment: Hi TigOldBitties, what I was thinking is setting a value for each line and calculating the distance from start to the position of the point for examples for line 1 setting a value of 1000 and then positioning the point in the step 200

Comment: Do you mean like so? http://jsfiddle.net/EY3dD/

Answer (score 0):

With such wide ranging values you might use a chart in which values increase by magnitude as you move rightward in the chart.

A common example of a Magnitude Chart is the Richter Scale which measures seismic activity.

Here's an example of your data values plotted on a chart that increases by a magnitude of 10X for each colored area on the chart.

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3fuwV/

[image]

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var data = [200, 20820, 32, 9999955, 7580];
    var scale=['0','10','100','1K','10K','100K','1M','10M','100M'];
    var scaleWidth=50;
    var xs=[];
    var nScale=[];
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++){
        xs.push(i*scaleWidth);
        nScale.push(Math.pow(10,i));
    }
    nScale[0]=0;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.25;
    //ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
    for(var i=7;i>=0;i--){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,150);
        ctx.lineTo(xs[i],150-i*5);
        ctx.lineTo(xs[i],175+i*5);
        ctx.lineTo(0,175);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.restore();

    for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xs[i],180+i*5);
        ctx.lineTo(xs[i],190+i*5);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillText(scale[i],xs[i],200+i*5);
    }

    plot();

    function plot(){
        for(var d=0;d<data.length;d++){
            var value=data[d];
            n=0;
            while(value/nScale[n]>10){ n++; }

            var pct=value/nScale[n+1];
            var x=parseInt(xs[n]+pct*scaleWidth);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,162,3,0,Math.PI*2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="black";
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x,162);
            ctx.lineTo(x,150-60-d*15);
            ctx.strokeStyle="black";
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.fillText(value,x+5,150-54-d*15);
        }
    }

    function randomColor(){ 
        return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    }

}; // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```